# Select(hightlight) Adjacent Rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to select a group of rows in datagridview. There is a dedicated simple function called

```
void SelectAdjacentRows(int i)
{
    if (i == -1)
        return;
    dgw.Rows[i].Selected = true;
    if (i < dgw.Rows.Count - 1)
        dgw.Rows[i + 1].Selected = true;
}
```

It is being invoked from CellClick event and rows gets selected correctly. But when I use Up/Down keys to navigate through grid view the selection is lost. I tried to use RowStateChanged event but then I ran into infinite loop even though I removed the event subscription like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        {
    dgw.RowStateChanged -= dataGridView1_RowStateChanged;
    SelectAdjacentRows(e.Row.Index);
    dgw.RowStateChanged += dataGridView1_RowStateChanged;
        }
}
```

How to make a selection when navigating using Up/Down keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a whole lot of luck dealing with the *State events on a DataGridView.  I would suggest looking into the [SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx).